# finding nth most occurring value in mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
alphabet occurrence

a 22
b 22
c 21
d 12
a 22
g 20
h 11
c 22
b 32
```

how to find 3rd most occurring value in this table using SQL Command.\

I am using something like:

> SELECT occurrence, COUNT(occurrence) from mytable group by occurrence
>   order by count(occurrence) desc limit 3;

```
output expected:
if n = 3
c count(occurrence of c) 
c 43
```

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: How would you handle ties?

Comment: added expected output, assume no ties

Comment: *most occurring value* : determined by sum of occurrences or count entries in table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offset to select nth number of row.
Here is the code for Selecting nth most occurred alphabet.

```
SELECT  alphabet,
COUNT(alphabet) AS value_occurrence 
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY alphabet
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this is the accepted answer as this only takes into account the number of rows, not the values of the occurrence column, which the OP seems to be looking for based on the question. Also, this returns the 4th row, not 3rd.

Answer (score 4):

a way to do this is to count the rows as you select them and filter off of that selection

```
SELECT letter, SUM(occurances) as num_occ, @A := @A + 1 as row_count
FROM occ, (select @A := 0) t
GROUP BY letter 
HAVING row_count = 3
ORDER BY num_occ DESC;
```

this is kind of a hacky way to do it. but since you dont have an ID in the table theres not much for an alternative

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e08/2)

EDIT:
after understanding the requirement better here is another alternative.

```
SELECT letter, SUM(occurances) as num_occ
FROM occ
GROUP BY letter 
ORDER BY num_occ DESC
limit 2, 1; -- 2 is the 3rd row position wise starting at 0 (think of an array)
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87453/4)

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` somewhere, you'd get a random row.

Comment: @Andreas mysql generally selects by insert order if there isn't one specified.. that being said it still could happen. if the OP had an ID or something to order it by I would have done that. but with just a letter and a count and wanting the natural insert order there isn't much I can do

Comment: But OP is specific about wanting the N'th highest occurrence, so GROUP BY `letter` and aggregate `occurrence` using COUNT or SUM (I was a bit confused on that one myself), then ORDER BY `occurrence` and select N'th row. The requested order is well defined, with OP's comment of "assume no ties".

Comment: @Andreas group by letter and sum the occurrences (the expected outcome is a sum of c 21, 22) c occurs twice. I cant order by letter or occurrence because it would mess up the natural insert order. n = 3 is the third row aka letter c. but if I order by letter then the 3rd row would be b. and if I order by occurrence it would have the wrong row at 3

Comment: There is nothing in question about natural insert order. Expected outputs are: N=1: `b 54`, N=2: `a 44`, N=3: `c 43`, N=4: `g 20`, N=5: `d 12`, N=6: `h 11`. At least, that's my understanding of the question.

Comment: @Andreas ah gotcha. I didn't get that from the OP.. question was worded weird